# jquery fadeOut behavng badly

Tags: php, fadein, fadeout, attr

While there have been many threads dealing with FadeIn/FadeOut, I believe I have a problem using these functions that is somewhat unique. I find it hard to believe that it may be bandwidth, but if it works flawlessly @ localhost and not so well online (10mbs account @ Comcast), then I'm not quite sure what to do.

OK. In a nutshell the DB serves up a bunch of thumbnails via the PHP gd_library. There is a div with a larger 450px placeholder image with an id="placeholder"

```
<p class="placeholderContainer"><img id="placeholder" 
src="product_getimage.php?path='.$path.'&amp;size='.$size.'" border="0" alt="" /></p>
```

The thumbs are spit out by a loop in this form

```
<a href="../images/products/'.$catNAME.'/'.$imgLOC.'/'.$imgName.'" 
title="'.$imgTitle.'"><img src="product_getimage.php?path='.$pathT.'&
amp;size='.$sizeT.'" border="1" id="'.$imgName.'" alt="" /></a>
```

All pretty straightforward stuff. You can see it in action @ transparentcable.com. Click on the products button, and then audio cables. Left hand sidebar is a list of links. Click anyone of them and the product loads in the above configuration.

Now here's, the jquery being used to run the simple click event on the thumbs(its all right there in the source code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#prod-thumbs a img').click(function() {
  var selImg = $(this).attr('id');
  var imagePath = "../images/products/<?php echo strtolower($catNAME);?>/<?php echo 
  $imgLOC; ?>/";
  var finalImg = imagePath + '/' + selImg;
  $('img#placeholder').fadeOut(500, function() {
   $('#placeholder').fadeIn(300).attr({src:finalImg});
   });
 return false;
 });
});
```

In essence it's just a variation on the old javascript image swap from years ago where the src of the image is changed. Same thing here.

Except, in this case, the fadeOut does its thing, but the placeholder image is still there, then it quickly is replaced when the fadeIn func runs. Like I said, works perfect here in the office on a WAMP system, but has that nasty little stumble online.

Everything is quite visible in the source code and any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: give as a url so we can see it in action

Comment: What's so surprising? you're loading the 'to fade' image **AFTER** the main page has completed, but don't wait for the image to load. No surprise it takes longer when you're testing it with a "real" connection instead of local.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the 'to fade' image is loaded before the click event as part of the DB call for a specific product. it's a placeholder image that is part of the DB record for that product. it loads by default in case the visitor does not click any of the thumbnail images.

Comment: oops ... someone had asked for a URI http://transparentcable.com/products/show_product.php?recID=77&perfID=2&catID=1&modCAT=1  ... try this link and see what i mean. i've also played around a bit with the fade in and out speeds and it definitely has an effect on the transition

Answer (score 0):

I think Marc B is on the right lines here. Have you tried:

```
$('#placeholder').attr({src:finalImg});
$('#placeholder').fadeIn(300);
```

?